# fast(est) XML editor

Tags: xml, editor, performance

Working with multiple XML documents  is incredibly slow with [Altova XMLspy](http://www.altova.com/xmlspy.html) and [Liquid XML Studio](http://www.liquid-technologies.com/Xml-Studio.aspx). When i am working with 3 Documents (100KB - 2MB) even switching between them takes over a second (its not a hardware issue, really) which is really frustrating.

There are so many XML editors out there that it would take a lifetime to try them all.

Features i need are formatting (pretty-printing), validating and similar simple stuff.

It has to "understand" Schema

The editor should have a GUI, but it doesn't have to be fancy.

Free or Open Source would be nice but not a must.

Cross-platform would be great, Windows is a must.

Speed is essential, magic features are secondary. 


So, what would you recommend?

Comment: "The editor should have a GUI" = "I don't want `curses`" or "I want WYSIWYG"?

Answer (score 5):

http://www.firstobject.com/dn_editor.htm

Is the best free XML editor i have ever used. It will open 100 MB documents in seconds.

Comment: evaluated all the free ones mentioned in this. This one is the best so far.

Answer (score 4):

I've just spent well over 3 minutes trying out  XmlMarker from http://symbolclick.com/index.htm and am pleased to discover it's lightening fast with 1.5MB files. Am impressed. The 2012 version has simultaneous live tree, text and data table views which is also impressed me.

I actually mostly using Sublime Text 2 though, because it's the best thing I've found for RegEx search and replace.

Comment: HOLY HECK this tackled my 180 meg XML file like it was NOTHING. <3 <3 <3

Comment: With the 2012 version XmlMarker turned into a 30-days trial as opposed to freeware in the previous version. 
And in the case you already use Eclipse it has a decent RegEx search and replace feature. Try for example Ctr+Space in the find/replace fields while 'Regex' is enabled and you'll also get a helpful cheatsheet.

Comment: Eclipse also does XML pretty-printing (Ctr+Shift+F).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't had any speed related issues using [oXygen](http://www.oxygenxml.com/). (I haven't had any issues at all really. I love oXygen.)

Answer (score 0):

There are two things that come to mind: Notepad++ and Visual Studio (Express editions should do the trick as well).

Notepad++ is a generic text editor with but basic text highlighting, but it has some plugins that enhance its XML-processing abilities. Reindenting is built in with TextFx. Since its so simple, large files are no problem for it.

Visual Studio uses XML files in many places, so it has a decent editor built in. It supports editing schemas (both with GUI and text-mode), automatic formatting, syntax highlighting, even a limited intellisense when a schema is present. The speed is also pretty decent, haven't seen any slowdowns even on larger documents.

**Added:** I'm not sure what "prettyprinting" is, but if it means reformatting a badly formatted XML document, then some googling revealed [this tool](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/). It's a command line utility, but you can add a command in NP++ menu for it. Also it's available as a library, so you can develop a NP++ plugin with it, if you really must.

Comment: I had trouble with the Notepad++ plugin for XML prettyprinting and validation. But if it works for OP, a very good option. Should be installed on every machine even if you're not actually programming - it's just a kickass text editor.

Comment: @delnan - I haven't used it myself, so I cannot say. But the plugins update every now and then, so maybe it's gotten better. :) And I agree for it being a kickass text editor. XD

Comment: I have NP++ installed, but was not aware of the pluguns. NP++ cant prettyprint XML out-of-the-box

Comment: Tried the XMLTools for NP++. The prettyprinting doesnt deliver :( It introduces some linebreaks but seems to be unable to handle indentation

Comment: @Vilx - I wouldn't use VS if I don't have to, for purely personal/emotional reasons.

Comment: @kostja - sorry to hear that, it's a very good tool. Anyways, what do you mean by "prettyprinting"?

Answer (score 0):

Was looking for the same thing not long time back. I found [XMLFox](http://www.xmlfox.com/). Free and faster than other commercial xml editors

Comment: Looked promising but it pukes when I try to open this 187 meg XML file :(

Comment: It took minutes to load my 5MB file.

Comment: It uses the Internet Explorer component to render the page and apparently also the MSXML parsing engine. Also has ads and nag screeens.

Answer (score 0):

Emacs nxml-mode is  good, has all the features you're after, and is very fast.

(I'll let commenters battle out as to whether Emacs has a GUI or not.)